# TYPO3 - external authentication of be_users with tx_sv_authbase

Tags: authentication, typo3, typo3-4.5

I am using TYPO3 4.5 and have to authenticate fe_users and be_users from an external source.

In my extension I have subclassed tx_sv_authbase and implemented the getUser() and authUser() functions.

For fe_users everything works fine! Depending on what I return in authUser() the login happens or not.

But I can't get it to work for be_users. Shouldn't it work exactly the same? No matter if I return 200 or true, I can't login with my extension. What could be the reason for this? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work now! Also the RSA encryption system which is default in TYPO3 6.2 is awesome! :)

The problem was in my getUser() function. There you have to map to existing users (if your user names from the external source aren't also contained in the TYPO3 database) and I forgot that my backend user name is different to my frontend user name.

The other confusing thing was that for some changes to take effect you always have to delete the cache files in typo3conf. This costed me some time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be exactly the same for be_users as for fe_users.

Please check ext_localconf.php, if both `authUserFE` and `authUserBE` are used as subtypes (seperated by comma).

I have created an [Yubikey OTP auth service](https://github.com/derhansen/sf_yubikey) for TYPO3, which authenticates local TYPO3 users with an Yubikey OTP. My extension does not use getUser(), but authentication works both for fe_users and be_users. Maybe this helps you debugging and fixing your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Does your extension also still work with TYPO3 6.2?

Comment: Thank you! Your example was very helpful!